# x-editable: stop sending data to the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, x-editable

I'm using x-editable from  https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html, and I 
used the following code to disallow it sending data to the server. But the code does not work and the plugin continues to send data to the server.

```
$(".editable").editable({
                send: 'never'
 });


<input class="editable  editable-click editable-empty dateinput form-control" data-clear="false" data-format="mm/dd/yyyy" data-name="date" data-original-title="" data-pk="10" data-type="date" data-url="/e/date/" id="name" name="date" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" required="required" type="text">
```

Comment: Can you post the html also?

Answer (score 0):

It's not properly documented at https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#editable, and might be considered a bug, but the logic within the save() method within EditableForm in editable-bootstrap.js makes it look pretty intentional that if 'url' option is defined, send=='never' is ignored.

The best way to prevent sending data to server is to set the url option to null until you wish to send.  If the value of the 'url' attribute is specific to the x-editable instance, then store that value in another attribute until it's needed.